# Querying by polygon boundary using Geopandas and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geopandas

I am really new to PostGIS (and PostgreSQL, for that matter) and I am having trouble figuring out how to query an existing table in a PG database with a polygon. I think I have identified the appropriate PG statement to use ([ST_Contains](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)) but it is not clear to me how I create the arguments for the statement from a geopandas dataframe. I'll walk you through a simple example of what I have thus far:

First, I load the relevant libraries:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import geopandas as gpd
```

Then I load the geodataframe I want to use to query the db:

```
poly = gpd.read_file('polygon.shp')
```

I have a database called 'my_db' and I create the connection:

```
dbname='my_db'
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/{dbname}')
```

This is where I get stuck.

How do I enter the geopandas geometries from "poly" into a format that PostGIS will understand?

```
sql = f'SELECT * FROM {dbname} WHERE ST_contains(poly[????], poly[????])'
queried_gdf = gpd.read_postgis(sql, engine, geom_col='geometry')
```

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing and matching in a weird way. You either want to store your spatial data in PostGIS or as a GeoDataFrame. If you want to store the data as a PostGIS table, you can use GeoPandas to [import the data into PostGIS](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis.html), and at that point you have the entire PostgreSQL/PostGIS querying engine at your disposal:

```
poly = gpd.read_file('polygon.shp')
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/{dbname}')
poly.to_postgis('my_table',engine)
```

At this stage, you have the data stored natively in a PostGIS table. Your next step depends on what you're trying to do. ST_Contains kind of suggests you have a bounding box or some other spatial feature in mind, so you could store that info in another table (say, 'bbox') and do:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table a INNER JOIN bbox b ON ST_Contains(b.geom,a.geom)'
queried_gdf = gpd.read_postgis(sql, engine)
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. I have a PostGIS database ("my_db") set up and want to query it. I only want the values from my_db that fall within "poly". I edited the original question to provide more clarity.

Comment: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_postgis.html#geopandas.read_postgis you have the correct function. Are you sure you want to query an entire database, rather than just a table?

Comment: Ha! I told you I was a newbie. Yes, I meant a table. I'll correct that and will try your suggestion above!

Comment: You'd want to  have 2 different tables  - 1 has the data you're trying to query, say points in a country, and the other one has the actual boundary you want to limit your query to, say a polygon layer of country boundaries. Does that more or less match your data and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is not a bounding box but many hexagonal polygons. Maybe I should perform a unary_union before putting into postgis? Although, this takes it out of geopandas DF and into shapely.

Comment: You're fine importing all of your data into PostGIS and doing the entire operation there. So dataset 1 is a set of polygons, and what's dataset 2? I.e., what are you querying with your hexagons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131497/discussion-between-jtam-and-encomium).